# Newest version of a library

Tags: updates, libraries

newbie here: how does it work, if Ubuntu currently features a certain version of a library but there is already a newer version of it at developer's site, do I have to wait for the next major release of Ubuntu to eventually incorporate it?

For example, currently in Ubuntu there is libabc-1.2-dev, but the developer already release 1.3. How to use it, apart from compiling it myself? In other words, when do new versions come into Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

To update your library, use [apt-get](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AptGet/Howto)

Comment: Thank you. Yes I know about apt-get, but this will update the library to latest version **in** Ubuntu. My question is, if there is already a newer version outside of Ubuntu, how quickly it gets included into default Ubuntu?

Comment: Oh sorry.  As far as I know, if there is a newer version outside of Ubuntu, that developer needs to have it in a repository(or publish their own repo).  Unnoffical repositories can be found here http://www.apt-get.org/